# Microsoft Visual C++ 2012: cannot find basic stuff

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Being new to Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012, I cannot find some basic things that I usually take for granted. It must be my fault for sure.

- How can I have multiple views of the same file? So far I have been able to split the file window vertically, but just once.
- Can I split it horizontally?
- Can I split it more than once?
- Can I just have the same file in multiple windows?
- Can I do some refactoring?
- Can I set bookmarks, to jump back and forth in the code?
- Can I have a list of bookmarks/breakpoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have multiple view of the same file go to the **Window** meni and select **New Window** This will show the file in multiple windows, which you'll be able to split.

For bookmarking go to the **Edit** menu and look at the **Bookmark** sub-menu near the bottom. It's got all the options you need for manipulating bookmarks.

For breakpoints go to the **Debug** menu, select the **Windows** sub-menu and pick the **Breakpoints** menu. It will display an window that allows you to manage all the breakpoint in the project you're working on.

To refactor just right-click in any file and you'll see a **Refactor** sub-menu that has a list of refactor actions.

Comment: Does Resharper work for C++? Really? Otherwise I have made good experience with [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/).

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi - It doesn't - my mistake! I had my C# hat half on!

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi, ReSharper is going to support C++: http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2013/06/26/resharper-to-support-c/